# is developing websites where users can add image gallery haram?

Tags: image

Hello i'm a web developer and i wanted to know if it was haram to develop websites where users and admin would add images, the images are for cultural events.

ps; i will not be taking pictures, not adding pictures, but i would give the tool 
Baraka allaho fikoum

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in that. As a matter of fact, there is nothing wrong with having a picture gallery like the above -or even taking those pictures if it is required from you.

In Islam what is generally accepted as Haram is drawings not actual pictures (which itself is also disputed).

Comment: thank you for your answer , it's hard to live as a Muslim in our world , i will wait for more answers , thanks again :)

Comment: @Rizerzero "it's hard to live as a Muslim in our world" i am disagree with this word, i am also a software engineer, personally i feel "Islam is the easiest religion in the world to follow"

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum,

Knowingly developing a tool for a website which would be dealing with Haram will get you into trouble. Otherwise, a tool is a tool, a phone for instance can be used for good and bad and so is a computer. The owners of the website could put text based images or pictures, that is up to them as to how they wish to use them.

However creating a website knowing that the owners would use it for haram purposes would be an issue.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

he who helps someone in haram task is also a equal shareholder and will  be punished equally...